# kmeans prediction using R

Tags: r, k-means

```
km <- kmeans(iris,3)

predict.kmeans <- 
 function(km, data)
 {k <- nrow(km$centers)
 n <- nrow(data)
 d <- as.matrix(dist(rbind(km$centers, data)))[-(1:k),1:k]
 out <- apply(d, 1, which.min)
 return(out)}

predict.kmeans(km,iris[1,])
# Error:apply(d, 1, which.min) : dim(X) must have a positive length
```

I have some problems with my simple code here,what's wrong with it?

Comment: @DWin - you got that far? I can't even run the first line assigning `km` without an error!

Comment: Impossible!It must have been your own problem.

Comment: Nope... fresh start, `kmeans(iris,3)` errors out. `kmeans(iris[1:4],3)` on the other hand works just fine.

Comment: 1. Explicitly specify variables `predict.kmeans(km,iris[1,1:4])`. 2. When you predict only one case (iris[1,1:4)) `d` becomes a vector not a matrix what causes an error on the next step.

Comment: @DrDom I think adding `drop = FALSE` would work equally equally good.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, `as.matrix` function doesn't have such an option, probably it will be better to use `as.data.frame(as.matrix(dist(rbind(km$centers, data))))[-(1:k),1:k]`.

Answer (score 2):

1. `kmeans` works on numerical matrices only. As @thelatemail pointed out, column 5 of `iris` isn't numeric.
2. you could use use `cl_predict` from `clue` instead of `predict.kmeans`

Comment: With the iris data, and I think with any similar data (mostly numerical, some factors), there's no point including the factors anyway. So `kmeans(iris[,1:4], n)` makes sense.